# What are the permission required for EC2 create Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-policies

I am trying to create a policy for giving the user the permission to create Ec2 instance but I dont wan't to give all the permission inside write.
Please verify if these permissions are enough or if some permission is extra

```
{
    "Version": "2020-06-16",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeImages",
                "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:CreateKeyPair"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm these permissions should work if using the [Console Wizard](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-ec2-console.html#ex-launch-wizard).

More examples of policies for other situations can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-ec2-console.html).

If you're ever in need of testing scenarios feel free to take a look at the [IAM policy simulator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html). It can really help you to validate your permissions against actions easily without having to script or attempt executing the change(s) each time.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to give create tag access, as for run instances it's a must needed option.Here I am attaching my policy for your refrence.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:DescribeImages",
            "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
            "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
            "ec2:DescribeInstances",
            "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
            "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
            "ec2:CreateTags",
            "ec2:DescribeInstanceTypes",
            "ec2:RunInstances",
            "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
            "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
            "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}